# S3 Bucket Policy for hotlinking is preventing writes

Tags: amazon-s3, railo

I have a website that serves our content from Amazon S3. Currently, I am able to read and write data to S3 just fine from my web server / website. The ACL permission are fine - I have full permissions for the website, and simply read permissions for the public.

Then, I added an S3 Bucket Policy to prevent hotlinking. You can see the S3 policy below.

This policy works well - except for one issue - it is now preventing file write requests from my webserver. So, while my public website serves content just fine, when I try to do file or directory operations, such as upload images or move images (or directories), I get an "Access denied" error now. (by my web application server, which is Railo / Coldfusion)

I'm not sure why this is happening? Initially I thought that it might be because the file read/write requests between my web server and S3 were coming via my IP and not my domain name.But even after adding my IP, the errors persist.

If I remove the policy, everything works fine again.

Does anyone know what is causing this or what I'm missing here? Thanks

```
       {
  "Version": "2008-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "Allowinmydomains",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "*"
      },
      "Action": "s3:GetObject",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::cdn.babeswithbraces.com/*",
      "Condition": {
        "StringLike": {
          "aws:Referer": [
            "http://www.babeswithbraces.com/*",
            "http://babeswithbraces.com/*",
            "http://64.244.61.40/*"
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "Sid": "Givenotaccessifrefererisnomysites",
      "Effect": "Deny",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "*"
      },
      "Action": "s3:GetObject",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::cdn.babeswithbraces.com/*",
      "Condition": {
        "StringNotLike": {
          "aws:Referer": [
            "http://www.babeswithbraces.com/*",
            "http://babeswithbraces.com/*",
            "http://64.244.61.40/*"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: What if you put the deny before the allow, or remove the "StringNotLike"/second policy block completely? The first "StringLike" condition should work to block any request not coming from your domain all on its own.

Comment: @Brian: Swapping them around does nothing. Removing the StringNotLike block allows all requests through thus making the hotlinking prevention void. I also read somewhere that you must have both the Allow and Deny blocks to make this effective, as it is when both are in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use bucket policies, a deny always overrides a grant. Because you are denying access to `GetObject` from your bucket policy for all accounts (including authenticated users) that don't match your specific referrers list, your app produces `Access denied` errors.

By default, objects in S3 have their ACLs set to private. If this is the case with your bucket, then there is no need to have an `Allow` and a `Deny` rule in your bucket policy. It would be enough to have an `Allow` condition that grants anonymous users, which match some specific referrers, the permission to access objects in the bucket.

In the case mentioned above, your bucket policy should look like:

```
{
  "Id": "Policy1380565362112",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "Stmt1380565360133",
      "Action": [
        "s3:GetObject"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::cdn.babeswithbraces.com/*",
      "Condition": {
        "StringLike": {
          "aws:Referer": [
            "http://www.babeswithbraces.com/*",
            "http://babeswithbraces.com/*",
            "http://64.244.61.40/*"
          ]
        }
      },
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": [
          "*"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

If the object ACLs already allow public access you can either remove those ACLs to make the objects private by default or include a `Deny` rule in your bucket policy and modify the requests you send to S3 from your app to include the expected referrer header. There is currently no way to have a `Deny` rule in your bucket policy that only affects anonymous requests.

Comment: Thanks a lot - your explanation really helped as well. The main  issue here was that my ACL permissions were set to allow public reads for that folder. Like you said, once I took away those ACL folder permissions and then added the "allow" policy, it worked perfectly.